# Sencha XTemplates issue with call from controller

Tags: sencha-touch, extjs

I am having some difficulty with XTemplates and using the MVC structure. I have went through a few of the tutorials and by themselves they make sense but when I try to apply them to what I am trying to accomplish it does not work that well.

First off, my app consists of TabBarMVC and several views. Some of the views will have 'sub views'. I have the app working from a 'layout' perspective. Tabs are tabbing and views can access subviews. Now the issue is sending data to subviews.

An example is my Bill page to Detail page. In the bill page a user can enter a total and number of people to split the bill against. My controller takes both parameters and divides them and stores them in a 'guests' object. My guests object will be an array of 1-x number of guest objects. (based on the number to split).

I then send that object to an update method in my sub view to update a XTemplate but that is not happening. I can alert the object, and view the data in debugger but I do not know how to update the Xtemplate.

Here is the controller code:

```
splitdetail: function(options)
{
    if ( ! this.splitdetailView)
    {
        var totalBill = options.data['totalBill'];
        var numGuests = options.data['splitBy'];

        var totalPerGuest = totalBill / numGuests;

        var guestObject = new Array();
        var theGuest;
        for (var i=0; i<numGuests; i++) {
            theGuest = {amount: totalPerGuest}
            guestObject.push(theGuest);
        }

        app.views.calculatorSplitDetail.updateWithRecord(guestObject);

        this.splitdetailView = this.render({
            xtype: 'CalculatorSplitDetail',
            switchAnimation: { type: 'slide'}
        });
    }

    this.application.viewport.setActiveItem(this.splitdetailView, 'slide');
},
```

and here is my split detail

```
var guestTemplate = new Ext.XTemplate(
'<tpl for=".">',
    '<div class=" x-field guest-amount-row x-field-number x-label-align-left">',
        '<div class="x-form-label" style="width: 30%; ">',
            '<span>Total bill</span>',
        '</div>',
        '<div class="x-form-field-container">',
            '<input type="number" name="totalGuestAmount" class="x-input-number" value="{amount}">',
        '</div>',
    '</div>',
'</tpl>'
);


app.views.CalculatorSplitDetail = Ext.extend(Ext.form.FormPanel, {
    initComponent: function() {

    Ext.apply(this, {
        scroll: false,
        items: [
            guestTemplate,
            ]

    });

    app.views.CalculatorSplitDetail.superclass.initComponent.call(this);

},

styleHtmlContent: true,
baseCls: 'calculator-splitdetail-panel',

updateWithRecord: function(record) {

    guestTemplate.apply(record);
    alert(record[0].amount);      
}
});

Ext.reg('CalculatorSplitDetail', app.views.CalculatorSplitDetail);
```

Answer (score 0):

`guestTemplate` is just a template, not a control, so it can't refresh itself, but it can generate new html for you. So all you need to do is update your panel with newly generated html:

```
updateWithRecord: function(record) {
    this.update(guestTemplate.apply(record));
    alert(record[0].amount);      
}
```